# WhenAny and ToProperty

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I think I am missing a fundamental Observable concept.

I have a ChargeViewModel class which has a ReactiveList property which is a collection of itself
ChargeViewModel.Charges which contains related charges

I want to observe the latest entry in the charges collection (it has a ChargeViewModel.lastModified)  and also have other properties in the UI based on the latest entry.

In the ctor I have this code which works to initialize the values; however it does not update the values for latestActionDate, latestBillToName, lastestNote when the observable variable "last" changes

I want the UI to update if the user updates the "last" charge or creates a new "last".

```
var last = Charges?
             .Changed
             .Select(_ => Charges.OrderByDescending(c => c.Model.LastModified).FirstOrDefault())
             .StartWith(Charges.OrderByDescending(c =>c.Model.LastModified).FirstOrDefault());

last
  .Select(c => c.Model.LastModified)
  .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.LatestActionDate, out latestActionDate);
last
  .Select(c => c.Model.BillToName)
  .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.LatestBillToName, out latestBillToName);
last
   .Select(c => c.Model.Note)
   .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.LatestNote, out latestNote);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReactiveList` (by default) only notifies upon elements added/moved/removed, not upon content changes. It's fairly simply to enable it (and maybe you already did) by setting `ChangeTrackingEnabled=true`.

However when enabled, you'll receive such motifications on `ItemChanged` observable, and not on `Changed` one, so in your case you probably need to do:

```
Charges.Changed.Select(_ => Unit.Default).Merge(Charges.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default))
    .Select(_ => /* ... */)
    ....
```